# sed + delete all words that not contain string before the "dot string"

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression

I castrated the following sed syntax in order to remove from file any host
that not contain linux/LINUX

```
 sed -i '/linux\|LINUX/!d' file
```

example

```
linux01.moon.com
solaris.moon.com
UNIX.foot.com
```

it will give

```
linux01.moon.com
```

but now we have other scenario that domains also include linux name as

```
linux01.room_linux.com
linux02.gt.com
linux03.klist.com
sol.linux.com
```

it will give

```
linux01.room_linux.com
linux02.gt.com
linux03.klist.com
sol.linux.com
```

instead of

```
    linux01.room_linux.com
    linux02.gt.com
    linux03.klist.com
```

so how to change my sed syntax in order to ignore the domain name if include linux or LINUX ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to select hosts with `linux` in the name as soon as they also have `linux` in the domain? Sure?

Comment: I want to ignore what is in the domain , so if domain include any linux/LINUX then it will not remove it

Comment: But then why don't you want `linux01.room_linux.com`? It *has* `linux` in the host name.

Comment: sorry I agree - you right

Comment: see my update , again I am very sorry about this - you right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the pattern to the start of the line with `^` and then allow only other characters than the dot (`[^.]*`) until your keyword is found:

```
sed -E '/^[^.]*(linux|LINUX)/!d'
```

Note that you need to add braces around your alternative patterns. I switched to extended regular expressions to make it more readable.

Comment: the problem is that - its removed all hosts in the file , so we get file empty

Comment: we have redhat 7.2 OS , on which OS you try it?

Comment: This can't be an OS version issue. If your `sed` accepts option `-E` it will work. Or do your lines contain other stuff before the host?

Comment: I means I use the syntax - sed -iE '/^[^.]*(linux|LINUX)/!d'   ( why -i flag cause remove of all hosts ? )

Comment: Never concatenate options after `-i`! This will make the `E` an argument (backup file extension) for the `-i` option and lose the `-E` option! Use `-i -E` or `-Ei`.

Comment: we must to use -i in order to update the file , we not want to redirect to other file

Comment: Yes, of course, use it. Just replace `-iE` with `-Ei` for the given reasons

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -e '
   h
   s/\..*//;y/linux/LINUX/;/LINUX/!d
   g
' inp.file
```

This is the Posix sed approach you could take.

Comment: Are you sure you want to write`y/linux/LINUX/` and not with `s/linux/LINUX/`? This will mess up all lines with big `L` and `I` and `N` and so on ...